# Do xarray or dask really support memory-mapping?

Tags: numpy, dask, numpy-memmap, python-xarray

In my experimentation so far, I've tried:

- `xr.open_dataset` with `chunks` arg, and it loads the data into memory.
- Set up a `NetCDF4DataStore`, and call `ds['field'].values` and it loads the data into memory.
- Set up a `ScipyDataStore` with `mmap='r'`, and `ds['field'].values` loads the data into memory.

From what I have seen, the design seems to center not around actually applying numpy functions on memory-mapped arrays, but rather loading small chunks into memory (sometimes using memory-mapping to do so). For example, [this comment](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/f517be7b1b3f41090eca04d06d7f434916861a7c/xarray/backends/scipy_.py#L51). And somewhat related comment [here](http://This%20works%20pretty%20cleanly,%20but%20in%20the%20process%20I%20discovered%20that%20there's%20no%20reliable%20way%20to%20check%20whether%20a%20numpy%20array%20is%20mem-mapped%20or%20not.%20The%20arrays%20scipy.io.netcdf%20returns%20are%20not%20np.memmap%20instances,%20but%20their%20data%20does%20point%20to%20a%20file%20on%20disk.) about not xarray not being able to determine whether a numpy array is mmapped or not.

I'd like to be able to represent and slice data as an `xarray.Dataset`, and be able to call `.values` (or `.data`) to get an `ndarray`, but have it remain mmapped (for purposes of shared-memory and so on).

It would also be nice if chunked dask operations could at least operate on the memory-mapped array until it actually needs to mutate something, which seems possible since dask seems to be designed around immutable arrays.

I did find a trick with xarray, though, which is to do like so:

```
data=np.load('file.npy', mmap_mode='r')
ds=xr.Dataset({'foo': (['dim1', 'dim2'], data)})
```

At this point, things like the following work without loading anything into memory:

```
np.sum(ds['foo'].values)
np.sum(ds['foo'][::2,:].values)
```

...xarray apparently doesn't know that the array is mmapped, and can't afford to impose a `np.copy` for cases like these.

Is there a "supported" way to do read-only memmapping (or copy-on write for that matter) in xarray or dask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xr.open_dataset` with `chunks=` should not immediately load data into memory, it should create a `dask.array`, which evaluates lazily.

```
testfile = '/Users/mdurant/data/smith_sandwell_topo_v8_2.nc'
arr = xr.open_dataset(testfile, chunks={'latitude': 6336//11, 'longitude': 10800//15}).ROSE
arr
```

`<xarray.DataArray 'ROSE' (latitude: 6336, longitude: 10800)>
dask.array</Users/mdurant/data/smith_sandwell_topo_v8_2.nc:/ROSE, shape=(6336, 10800), dtype=float64, chunksize=(576, 720)>
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 0.0166667 0.05 0.0833333 0.116667 0.15 ...
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -72.0009 -71.9905 -71.9802 -71.9699 ...
Attributes:
    long_name:               Topography and Bathymetry (  8123m -> -10799m)
    units:                   meters
    valid_range:             [-32766  32767]
    unpacked_missing_value:  -32767.0`

(note the dask.array in the above)

Many xarray operations on this may be lazy, and work chunkwise (and if you slice, only required chunks would be loaded)

```
arr.sum()
```

`<xarray.DataArray 'ROSE' ()>
dask.array<sum-aggregate, shape=(), dtype=float64, chunksize=()>`

```
arr.sum().values    # evaluates
```

This is not the same as memory mapping, however, so I appreciate if this doesn't answer your question.

With dask's threaded scheduler, in-memory values are available to the other workers, so sharing would be quite efficient. Conversely, the distributed scheduler is quite good at recognising when results can be reused within a computation graph or between graphs.

Comment: I was thinking it would be cool if xarray/dask supported memory-mapping through-and-through. But on the other hand, lazy-loading of chunks is almost functionally equivalent.

I assume that xarray is using the dask.threaded scheduler by default.

I'm building a server around an xarray/CF-style data model (for web visualization apps to access & query via websocket), and am trying to decide whether to rely on the memmapping hack I described above along with my own parallelization, versus going full-in on dask.

Comment: The data itself is read-only, but for some queries it may be useful to compute a dynamic mask array based on some parameters/filters. This is where a mutable sharedmem array might come in handy. Though using dask to compute the mask with each request might be fine as well. I have more investigating to do on my own. I will probably accept your answer though BTW since my question seems to be asking about unsupported/undocumented aspects of xarray which is a tall order.

Comment: Yes, dask uses the threaded scheduler by default, and therefore so does xarray, unless you created a distributed Client. For HDF files, this is desirable, since there can be inter-process file locking issues otherwise. For interactive visualisation of large datasets via xarray/dask, you may wish to look into [datashader examples](https://github.com/bokeh/datashader/tree/master/examples).

Comment: I was worried that a task graph such as `((arr>0.75)*arr).sum()` would eat up a lot of memory, since the `(arr>0.75)` intermediate calculation is the size of the full array. But now it seems obvious to me that the footprint will just be chunksize*Nthreads. I think this will work great for my application, without any need for memmapping. I am doing server-side statistical queries using functions such as `da.einsum`, while the visualization component is quite simple as of now. Datashader looks amazing, and thanks for the HDF locking tip.